# Deadlock because of index on DELETE statement (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I am using `SQL Server 2016`.
I have an entity with a child entity (`child_entity`) which also has a child entity (`second_child_entity`).

> So: entity <- child_entity <- second_child_entity

These are mapped in `Java` as `JPA` entities with `@OneToOne` relationships on the children. Each entity has a primary key and the children have foreign keys to these parents with `DELETE CASCADE`. Also the children have non-unique, non-clustered indexes on their foreign key columns.

Now when multiple processes attempt to delete some of the base entities (e.g. `delete from entity where id=...`) a `deadlock` can occur on the second child (see deadlock graph). It seems like the index is the problem. Is there a way I can prevent this `deadlock` from happening?

It was suggested in the comments SQLServer locks too many rows due to a missing index on `file_id`. This sounds like a good idea, but unfortunately there's already is an index on that column (it was missing in the table definition SQL generated by MSSQL, I added, see below). But perhaps it is the wrong kind of index?

[deadlock graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcdEP.png)

---

Some more info in case it helps:

- The SQL is generated via Hibernate in a JavaEE webapp.
- Query plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByzQzfshu

[image: query plan]

- Connection settings

```sql
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language Deutsch
set dateformat dmy
set datefirst 1
set transaction isolation level read committed
```

- Table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[filedata_form_record_data](
    [id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [data] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [lockingversion] [int] NULL,
    [file_id] [bigint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_fd_form_record_data] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[filedata_form_record_data]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk_filedata_fr_data_file_id] FOREIGN KEY([file_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[file_form_record_data] ([id])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[filedata_form_record_data] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_filedata_fr_data_file_id]
GO



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[file_form_record_data](
    [id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [lockingversion] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [date_created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [date_modified] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [user_name_created] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [user_name_modified] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [entity_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [filesize] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_file_form_record_data] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[file_form_record_data]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk_file_fr_data_entity_id] FOREIGN KEY([entity_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[form_record_data] ([id])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[file_form_record_data] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_file_fr_data_entity_id]
GO
```

- Indices that present in the table

```sql
/****** Object:  Index [idx_fd_f_r_data-file]    Script Date: 01.07.2021 14:13:38 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_fd_f_r_data-file] ON [dbo].[filedata_form_record_data]
(
    [file_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [pk_fd_form_record_data]    Script Date: 01.07.2021 14:13:53 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[filedata_form_record_data] ADD  CONSTRAINT [pk_fd_form_record_data] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

- Deadlock as XML

```xml
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process1adee531848">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process1adee531848" taskpriority="0" logused="2780" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594057195520 (302f8a02e9bb)" waittime="4986" ownerId="6320599" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-06-28T11:45:51.043" XDES="0x1add5d02d68" lockMode="RangeS-U" schedulerid="10" kpid="11816" status="suspended" spid="60" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2021-06-28T11:45:51.060" lastbatchcompleted="2021-06-28T11:45:51.060" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.060" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="WIN-32RVKN5Q436" hostpid="0" loginname="formcycle" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="6320599" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="40" stmtend="176" sqlhandle="0x0200000051b59e00f80c9b670f0625a49e64fac810ed77f60000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@P0 bigint,@P1 int)delete from file_form_record_data where id=@P0 and lockingVersion=@P1    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process1adeeececa8" taskpriority="0" logused="2780" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594057195520 (99a93231f07b)" waittime="7957" ownerId="6320660" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-06-28T11:45:51.093" XDES="0x1ade82ca8b8" lockMode="RangeS-U" schedulerid="6" kpid="8988" status="suspended" spid="62" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2021-06-28T11:45:51.107" lastbatchcompleted="2021-06-28T11:45:51.103" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.103" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="WIN-32RVKN5Q436" hostpid="0" loginname="formcycle" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="6320660" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="40" stmtend="176" sqlhandle="0x0200000051b59e00f80c9b670f0625a49e64fac810ed77f60000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@P0 bigint,@P1 int)delete from file_form_record_data where id=@P0 and lockingVersion=@P1    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594057195520" dbid="5" objectname="formcycle.dbo.filedata_form_record_data" indexname="idx_fd_f_r_data-file" id="lock1add5ba4180" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594057195520">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process1adeeececa8" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process1adee531848" mode="RangeS-U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594057195520" dbid="5" objectname="formcycle.dbo.filedata_form_record_data" indexname="idx_fd_f_r_data-file" id="lock1adb70f2800" mode="RangeS-U" associatedObjectId="72057594057195520">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process1adee531848" mode="RangeS-U"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process1adeeececa8" mode="RangeS-U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

Comment: …what is the transaction isolation level?

Comment: Transaction level is the default from HikariCP / Microsoft JDBC driver: `set transaction isolation level read committed`

Comment: You need an index on `filedata_form_record_data (file_id)` this should fix the deadlock. But please add the deadlock **as XML** (not whatever format you have in that snippet), also please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: Query plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByzQzfshu

Comment: Yeah almost certainly missing index, you got a huge index scan in the foreign-key cascade section `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_filedata_form_record_data__file_id ON filedata_form_record_data (file_id);`

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for the suggestion and yes, I had been wondering about the query plan as well. Although we've already got an index on that column, see the updated question (didn't show up in the generated table definition). When I look at the index in SQL management studio, it says `non-unique, ungrouped`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Actually looking at it again, I can see the index *is* being used, only it's gone for a scan with merge join. It would only do this if it thinks that a very large proportion of the table is going to be deleted, but [sometimes it can make mistakes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106319/overcome-merge-joinindex-scan-with-explicit-single-key-value-on-a-foreign-key). Things you could try: `UPDATE STATISTICS filedata_form_record_data ([idx_fd_f_r_data-file]) WITH FULLSCAN;` might help. Next is to force a loop join by adding `OPTION (LOOP JOIN)` on the query, this shouldn't .....

Comment: .... affect any other part of the query because there is only that join. A *very* last resort is disable row and page locking on `filedata_form_record_data`, this means that the whole table gets locked, and prevents the deadlock.